# Select a recording based on the meta

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have have the following tables

**Meta table**

```
id | recording_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

**Recording Table**

```
id | recording
```

The `recording_id` on the `meta_table` is a foreign key that points towards a recording on the recording table.

Now I have a associative array `$metas` from my `$_GET` with meta keys and values and I want to `SELECT` the recordings that match all the meta keys and values. How would I do that?

This is what I have so far. How do I add an array into my bind param? And am I on the right track?

I just cannot wrap my head around this.

```
function retrieveRecordingsByMetaData($connection, $config, $metas, $limit)
{
    $where = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($metas); $i++) {
        $where .= "meta_key=? AND meta_value=? AND ";
    }
    $where = preg_replace('/ AND $/', '', $where);

    $sql = "SELECT recording_id 
    FROM $config->meta_table 
    WHERE " . $where . " 
    INNER JOIN $config->recording_table 
    ON $config->meta_table.id=$config->recording_table.id 
    LIMIT ?";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($metas as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $key);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $limit);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error . " \r\n";
        die();
    }

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "recording found";
            //$recording = $row["recording"];
            //$hex = bin2hex($recording);
            //echo ("response=recording" . $id . "=" . $hex . "\r\n");
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results \r\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write this query just in SQL, you would write something like

```
SELECT r.id
FROM recording r
JOIN meta m ON m.recording_id = r.id
           AND (m.meta_key = 'key1' AND m.meta_value = 'value1'
             OR m.meta_key = 'key2' AND m.meta_value = 'value2'
             OR m.meta_key = 'key3' AND m.meta_value = 'value3'
                ...)
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = <count of all key/value pairs>
LIMIT 10
```

The `HAVING` clause is what asserts that a recording has all of the specified meta key and value pairs.

To translate that into your PHP code, you need to build up your `$where` clause in a similar manner; I prefer using an array and imploding to save worrying about trailing `AND` and the like. At the same time as we are building that clause, we can build the inputs to `bind_param`:

```
$join = array();
$params = array();
$types = '';
foreach ($metas as $key => $value) {
    $join[] = 'm.meta_key=? AND m.meta_value=?';
    $params[] = $key;
    $params[] = $value;
    $types .= 'ss';
}
// add the parameter for the `HAVING` check
$params[] = count($metas);
$types .= 'i';
// add the limit
$params[] = $limit;
$types .= 'i';
// make the query string
$sql = "SELECT recording_id 
        FROM {$config->recording_table} r
        JOIN {$config->meta_table} m ON m.recording_id = r.id
         AND (" . implode(' OR ', $join) . ")
        GROUP BY r.id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = ?
        LIMIT ?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Prepare failed: " . $conn->error . "\n";
    die();
}
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error . " \r\n";
    die();
}
```

A demo of the query formation and params generation can be found [here](https://3v4l.org/eR6bL).