# MYSQL - How do I use a SELECT as my WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I have two tables `recordings` and `recording_metas` and I want to select some metas and use the foreign keys from those metas to find the corresponding recording. This is what I have so far. `$recording_sql` outputs this

```
SELECT recording FROM recordings 
    INNER JOIN recording_metas 
    ON recordings.id = recording_metas.recording_id
    WHERE recording_metas.recording_id IN (SELECT recording_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM recording_metas WHERE meta_key=? AND meta_value=?) LIMIT ?
```

But why do I get the following error?

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool
```

at this line `$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($mixed)), ...$mixed);` I'm sure that `$meta_sql` works because I tested it separately with the LIMIT pointer in there aswell so the pointers are working fine if I use them on `$meta_sql`

**PHP**

```
function retrieveRecordingsByMetaData($connection, $config, $metas, $limit)
{
    $where = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($metas); $i++) {
        $where .= "meta_key=? AND meta_value=? AND ";
    }
    $where = preg_replace('/ AND $/', '', $where);

    $meta_sql = "SELECT recording_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM $config->meta_table WHERE $where";

    $recording_sql = "SELECT recording FROM $config->recording_table 
    INNER JOIN $config->meta_table 
    ON $config->recording_table.id = $config->meta_table.recording_id
    WHERE $config->meta_table.recording_id IN ($meta_sql) LIMIT ?";

    echo ($recording_sql);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($recording_sql);

    $mixed = associativeToArrayMixed($metas);
    array_push($mixed, $limit);
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($mixed)), ...$mixed);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error . " \r\n";
        die();
    }

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "recording found";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results \r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to `var_dump($stmt)` ?

Comment: it suggests that the `prepared statement` failed - fork the logic to test for `if ( $stmt ){GOOD} else{BAD}`

Comment: It outputs false, but what do I do with this info?

Comment: do it right after `$stmt = $connection->prepare($recording_sql);`

Comment: so something is wrong, actually user nbk already responded with the issue you have, select statement must match your where clause

Comment: @MikeOttink did you see my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186340/select-a-recording-based-on-the-meta)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to select only one columns in your where clause

```
WHERE recording_metas.recording_id IN 
  (SELECT recording_id FROM recording_metas WHERE meta_key=? AND meta_value=?) LIMIT ?
```

If you want to select more than one column you have to use tupels like shown here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44706402/5193536

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer, you my good sir are a smart man!